# jQuery DataTables features are not available

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I have an issue with the DataTables plugin , I have already managed to make it work on another project, but in this one it doesn't work and I don't know why.

It seems like it's only the jQuery part that is not working because I have already CSS elements, and the function with the DataTable function works, but nothing happened when I try for example to use the search input, or order by column of my table

Here's my HTML/PHP :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Formulaire de recherche bitrix24</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
.......
.......

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <table class="table table-hover table-responsive display" id="table_1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Titre</th>
                            <th scope="col">Prénom</th>
                            <th scope="col">Prospect créé le </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
            foreach($result as $key1){
                ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row"><?php echo $key1['ID']; ?></th>
                            <td><?php  echo  $key1['TITLE']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $key1['NAME']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php $date_create=$key1['DATE_CREATE']; echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y à %H h %M ", strtotime($date_create)); ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php
            }
            ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
......
......

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

and here's my js part in another file (js/scripts.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#table_1').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        language: {
            processing: "Traitement en cours...",
            search: "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
            lengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            info: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            infoEmpty: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
            infoFiltered: "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
            infoPostFix: "",
            loadingRecords: "Chargement en cours...",
            zeroRecords: "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
            emptyTable: "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
            paginate: {
                first: "Premier",
                previous: "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
                next: "Suivant",
                last: "Dernier"
            },
            aria: {
                sortAscending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
                sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Here's what I have :
https://i.ibb.co/fkBdx51/Capture.png

[image]

So, I have all CSS elements, my table is well recognize by my jQuery function function, but none of JS elements are working like said above.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: No I have no error in the console :/

Comment: the `"bDestroy": true` property looks obsolete. Do you have any result with `"destroy": true` ?

Comment: Nothing changed with "destroy": true
I have also tried to put the basic function :



   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table_1').DataTable();
    });

and it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've just resolve the issue, my foreach loop wasn't at the right spot, it was creating multiple tbody tag.

I've changed the place of my loop and now it works.